# Problema ao carregar arquivos estáticos nas rotas com nodeJS / expressJS

Tags: node.js, express.js, ejs

Programando meu primeiro sistema me deparei com um probleminha... estou criando um sistema de clientes e alterei a estrutura da pasta views da seguinte maneira:

- /app

  - /views

    - /clientes

      - clientes.ejs
      - adicionar.ejs
    - /usuarios

      - usuarios.ejs
      - adicionar.ejs

Até aí, tudo certinho, rotas, controllers e models. Mas quando clico no botão com a rota "/clientes/adicionar" que leva pra "/clientes/adicionar.ejs" ele carrega a página ok, mas os caminhos do static são alterados, tentando buscar em "/clientes/css" ou "/clientes/img", onde o certo seria "/css" e "/img".

Como faço para resolver esse problema com várias páginas nas views?

/app/routes/clientes.js

```
module.exports = function(application){

    application.get('/clientes', function(req, res){
        application.app.controllers.clientes.cadastrar(application, req, res);
    });

    application.get('/clientes/adicionar', function(req, res){
        application.app.controllers.clientes.adicionar(application, req, res);
    });

}
```

/app/controllers/clientes.js

```
module.exports.clientes = function (application, req, res){
    res.render('clientes/clientes', {validacao: {}, dadosForm: {}});
}

module.exports.adicionar = function(application, req, res){
    res.render('./clientes/adicionar');
}

module.exports.cadastrar = function(application, req, res){
    res.send('tudo ok');
}
```

no server.js a configuração do static express

```
app.use(express.static('./app/public'));
```

Comment: Acho que esse problema está no lado do cliente... como estão os caminhos nos links do HTML que estás a gerar?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, o problema era inserir a "/" antes do caminho, buscando na raiz e não pegando o caminho relativo.